# Exercise 4 of Chapter 1 of Liebeck's Concise Introduction to Pure Mathematics

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I am working with the book of Professor Liebeck 'A Concise Introduction to Pure Mathematics'.
Exercise 4, Chapter 1. (Even numbered exercises have neither hints nor solutions.)

[image]

($\bar{A}$ denotes the nagation of statement $A$.)

Statement (d) implies (e) and vice versa. I do not see other possibilities. Am I right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: To see that $(d)\implies (a)$:  If $A$ is true then we have $(a)$, of course.  If $A$ is false then $\overline A$ is true so we have $B$, and again we have $(a)$.

Comment: It's your problem...for what I was writing, I certainly assumed it was inclusive, which I regard as the default meaning of the word.  That is "A or B" is true if either $A,B$ are true and it is false if both $A,B$ are false.  If you meant the exclusive or you should edit to make that clear.

Comment: @Lulu if $A$ and $B$ are both false then $(a)$ is false and $(b)$ and $(c)$ are true. $(b)$ is equivalent to $B$ is false or $A$ is true, for example. I don't think I am mad ...

Comment: Dimitris, useful fact: `P⇒Q` is defined as `¬P∨Q`. $\quad$ Among (a) to (e), the only implications are that (a),(d),(e) are equivalent to one another.

Comment: @ryang It is clear now! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ryang Should it better an answer rather than comments?

Comment: @Dimitris My preference is that you delete this page, or write a self-answer. -) $\quad$  BTW, do remember to upvote/accept useful answers to your recent questions...helps this site function better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the useful comments, I post here an answer.

First, the negation of $\bar{A}\Rightarrow B$ is $\bar{B}\Rightarrow A$ and vice versa. That is,

$\bar{A}\Rightarrow B\iff \bar{B}\Rightarrow A$

so that (d) implies (e) and  (e) implies (d).

Furthermore, (a) implies (d) for (a) says that either $A$ is true or $B$ is true. Thus, if $A$ is not true (so $\bar{A}$ is true), then $B$ must be true. But, this is exactly statement (d). In a similar manner,  (a) implies (e), since if $B$ is not true (so $\bar{B}$ is true), then $A$ must be true. But, this is exactly statement (e).

Since (d) and (e) have been shown to be equivalent, one concludes  that (a),(d),(e) are equivalent to one another.

Next, we shall prove that neither (b) nor (c) imply (a), (d) and (e). We shall do it by a counterexample. Let $x$ be some real number. Let $A$ be the statement $x>6$, and let $B$ be the statement $x>2$.

Then (b) is is true, since $A\Rightarrow B$ means that if $x>6$ then $x>2$ which is clearly true.

But, (a) is wrong, since it means that $x>2$ (either $A$ is true or $B$ is true). But all we know about $x$ is that it is a real number.

Similarly, (c) is wrong, since it says that if $x>2$, then $x>6$, which is not true in general.

In addition, (d) is wrong, for it says that if $x\leq 6$, then $x>2$, which is not true in general.

Finally, (e) is wrong,  for it says that if $x\leq 2$, then $x>6$, which is absurd.

Therefore, we have demonstrate, via a a counterexample,  that (b) does not imply
any of the other statements. Working in a similar manner,  one can show that (c) does not imply
any of the other statements as well.

To sum up, the only implications are that statements (a),(d),(e) are equivalent to one another.

Comment: If (a) were to imply (d), then B would be proven.